# Is subtracting larger unsigned value from smaller in C++ undefined behaviour?

Tags: c++, unsigned, signed, subtraction

In a program below after "integral promotions" and "usual arithmetic conversions" both operands of operator `-` remain `unsigned long long`. Afterwards, C++11 standard says:

> 5.7.3 The result of the binary - operator is the difference resulting from the subtraction of the second operand from the first.

Does the standard define anywhere in more detail how exactly the subtraction is performed (or refers to some other document that defines it)?

Does subtracting a larger unsigned integer from smaller unsigned integer produce an undefined behavior or not and why?

Does performing an assignment `c=a-b` as in the example program below guarantee that `c` will be `-3` on ALL (even theoretically) possible machine architectures compliant with C++11 standard and why?

```
int main()
{
    unsigned long long a=2, b=5;
    signed long long c=a-b;
}
```

Comment: The subtraction is done in unsigned arithmetic, and only then converted to signed.

Comment: unsigned arithmetics always wrap around (mod 2^n)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The subtraction of unsigned values is well-defined by (3.9.1) [basic.fundamental]/4:

> Unsigned integers, declared `unsigned`, shall obey the laws of arithmetic modulo 2<sup>*n*</sup> where *n* is the number of bits in the value representation of that particular size of integer.<sup>46</sup>
>
> <sup>46)</sup> This implies that unsigned arithmetic does not overflow because a result that cannot be represented by the resulting unsigned integer type is reduced modulo the number that is one greater than the largest value that can be represented by the resulting unsigned integer type.

However, the assignment causes `c` to have an implementation-defined value (that is to say, your mileage may vary). About assignment operators, (5.17) [expr.ass]/3 has to say

> If the left operand is not of class type, the expression is implicitly converted (Clause 4) to the cv-unqualified type of the left operand.

And Clause 4 ([conv]) says in (4.7) [conv.integral]/3

> If the destination type is signed, the value is unchanged if it can be represented in the destination type (and bit-field width); **otherwise, the value is implementation-defined.**

To reiterate: `a - b` is well-defined, `c = a - b` is not because the result of `a - b` is not representable by `c`.

The historical reason for this is that while today virtually all computers use two's complement representation for signed integers, back in the olden days there were machines that used [other representations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations) (notably one's complement and signed magnitude) that do not have the same value range as two's complement. Had unsigned-to-signed conversion been defined in terms natural for two's complement representation, C++ would have been impossible (or  at least very difficult) to implement on such machines, and had it been defined in terms natural for one of those representations, we'd have a bigger problem today.

Comment: Will the `signed long long c = static_cast<signed long long>(a)-static_cast<signed long long>(b);` be well-defined and guarantee c == -5 for all values of a and b equal or below `std::numeric_limits<signed long long>::max()` ?

Comment: `c == -3`, but yes for the given values. `a - b` with signed `a` and `b` is well-defined with the value of `-3`, and `c` can represent that value. There are value combinations of `a` and `b` that over- or underflow, though, and there the value is implementation-defined again.

Comment: @Wintermute: Actually casting to signed before subtracting results in **undefined**, not implementation-defined behavior, if the result of the subtraction overflows or underflows. Casting to signed after subtracting unsigned values is, as you quote from the spec, implementation-defined.

Comment: @Nemo True, if the subtraction over- or underflows it's undefined behavior. I'm editing in the relevant paragraph at the moment.

Comment: Oh, wait -- brain fart. It's actually well-defined the way OP asks. If both `a` and `b` are between `0` (because they're unsigned) and `std::numeric_limits<signed long long>::max()`, the result of `a - b` with `a` and `b` cast to signed is a number representable by `signed long long`. So that's fine. Aborting irrelevant edit (was about to quote (5) [expr]/4).

Comment: Hmm...although: It does not seem to be guaranteed that `-std::numeric_limits<signed long long>::max()` is representable by `signed long long`, or at least I can't find anything about it. It is going to be (literally!) everywhere, but to be perfectly nitpicky, there doesn't seem to be anything in the standard that prohibits an implementation where the negative value range of signed integer types is smaller (rather than larger, as we're used to today) than the positive.

Comment: @Wintermute: Right, but if the values are between `0` and `std::numeric_limits<unsigned long long>::max()`, the result of `a - b` with `a` and `b` cast to signed could certainly lie outside the representable range and result in undefined behavior. Anyway your answer is perfectly correct to the question as phrased so +1

Answer (score -1):

The result of `a - b` is well-defined as C++ guarantees two's complement semantics for them, if I recall correctly. However, the resulting underfklow would be outside the range of `signed long long` and therefore converting this value to a signed `long long` will be undefined behaviour.

Comment: Two's complement for *unsigned* arithmetic??

Comment: This is wrong twice... First, as @OliverCharlesworth says, two's complement is only a meaningful concept for signed values. Second, casting out-of-range unsigned values to signed is not integer overflow and is only implementation-defined (not undefined) behavior.